# Exporting phonegap android app

Tags: android, mobile, cordova, export

This will probably seem like a noob question but I have managed to intall phonegap with eclipse and to get the emulator and samples running. However, I am confused on how I would export this inorder to try it on my phone. Is it the .apk file in the /bin folder of the application? Or is there more? I mean like pictures and other files. I'm not used to eclipse. How do I get it on my phone and eventually the market(free only apps).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's the APK file that is the application. You should also be able to connect your device to your computer and run directly on it.

http://www.phonegap.com/start/#android